# How to create review site with Drupal 7.7, FiveStar 2.x-dev, Node Reference URL, and Unique field?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, rating

How to create review site with Drupal 7.7, FiveStar 2.x-dev, Node Reference URL, and Unique field?

Configuration:

1. Drupal 7.7
2. FiveStar 2.x-dev
3. Node Reference URL Widget
4. Unique field
5. Bartik theme

What I have now are:

1. Product node
2. User can write a review and rate each product node with multiaxis fivestar (value, price, and reliability).
3. User can create only one review per product (unique field module).
4. Rating is available when User create a Review node (Node Reference URL).

Questions:

1. How to embedded product node on the top of the review node? I want user to see what they are voting for without going back to the product node page.
2. How to create average rate of each category (value, price, and reliability) using Views?
3. How to compute average of all rating categories values? It means to create one number computed from average rating of value, price, and reliability.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers. This question is too broad; it is not possible to describe how to configure 3 modules to implement the wanted feature. You are also asking three different questions in the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, its simple and clear about the topic http://drupal.org/node/1308114 only the thing you need is to just spend couple of minutes on it, you'll surely get what you are trying to achieve.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make good review site with those mentioned but still now there isn't any plugin or hack for achieving Google Review Snippets.

http://drupal.org/node/901260